# Concatenate javascript files in eclipse? (PureMVC Mootools)

Tags: javascript, mootools, puremvc

I just started to work with the pureMVC tutorials with javascript. In the Objs-Platform, there was some nice ObjsComp.jar, which concatenate all javascript files in my a specific folder into one file.

Now I m working with the Mootools-Platform, which doesn't offer such a script. Any suggesntions or other tools?

Thanks K

Comment: Offtopic, but related: outside Eclipse, for a Rails app, you could also deploy Rails asset_packager by defining all JavaScript files in the YML file. That way you can automate it in the deployment and there's no manual labour at all. See https://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use apache ant to do this for my mootools projects, you might find these links helpful to get started.

[How do I concatenate JavaScript files into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301442/how-do-i-concatenate-javascript-files-into-one-file)

http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/16/

http://ant.apache.org/

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html