# Concat in npm using a glob input (no Grunt or Gulp)

Tags: node.js, build, npm

I am experimenting with [using npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).

I'd like to do something simple, just concat all the css files together. I can't find an npm module that does only that. there is [concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat), but it has no CLI interface. There are lots of gulp/grunt plugins that do it, but I don't want those dependencies for this experiement. I also understand I can use unix's `cat`:

```
cat a.css b.css > all.css
```

But this doesn't support globbing. I'd like to be able to do this:

```
concat app/**.css > dist/all.css
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See my solution for a similar question > https://stackoverflow.com/a/75336590/7472479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on linux, you can use `cat`.

```
cat app/*.css > all.css
```

If you want to search the folders recursively, use `find`.

```
find app -name "*.css" -exec cat {} \; > all.css
```

Since you wanted something node-specific, you could use [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Save the following as **concat.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    args = process.argv.splice(2);

if(args.length !== 2)
    return console.log('Incorrect usage. "node concat [glob] [output file]"');

if(fs.exists(args[1]))
    fs.unlinkSync(args[1]);
glob.sync(args[0]).forEach(function(file) {
    fs.appendFileSync(args[1], fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'));
});
```

Then you'd use

```
node concat app/**/*.css all.css
```

Or since you're using build scripts, have the following in **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node concat app/**/*.css all.css",
}
```

and

```
npm build
```

Comment: Doesn't this only go one level deep?

Comment: Yes. You could do it recursively with `find`.

Comment: works great. prefer something in node so it's platform independent, but we'll see if anyone else knows a way

Comment: Added a node version.