# Concatenate files with npm as build tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, concatenation

I recently discovered that I can use npm as a task runner instead of gulp or grunt, everything is fantastic so far (lint, stylus, jade, uglify, watch .. etc) but the concatenation part, I cannot seem to achieve that. With gulp it was something like:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('www/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/dist'))
    .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/dist'));
});
```

Is there a way I can do that with npm?

To be more clear, my goal is to do something like this:

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "f_todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concat": "^1.0.0",
    "rerun-script": "^0.6.0",
    "stylus": "^0.53.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "stylus": "stylus ss --compress --out lib/stylesheets",
    "concat": "concat dependency code would be here",
    "dev": "rerun-script"
  },
  "watches": {
    "stylus": "ss/**"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `concat` package you where using for inspiration?

Comment: Yes, but i need something like `concat js/** --out all.js` in my package.json scripts object

Comment: See my solution for a similar question > https://stackoverflow.com/a/75336590/7472479

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
var concat = require('concat')    
concat(['a.css', 'b.css', 'c.css'], 'all.css')
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat

and don't forget about `npm install concat`

**By command**
use `concat-glob-cli`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "concat": "concat-glob-cli -f path/to/**/*.js -o bundle.js",
    ...
 },
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-glob-cli

Comment: Hey thank you for your time, but im trying to achieve the concatenation using NPM as build tool, adding in my package.json something like this  `"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "stylus": "cat ss new.styl && stylus ss --compress --out lib/stylesheets",
    "dev": "rerun-script"
  },
  "watches": {
    "stylus": "ss/**"
  }`

Comment: I added another variant, try it

Comment: Yey! it did the trick, i had to change this part `"concat": "concat-glob-cli -f path/to/**/*.js -o bundle.js",` to `"concat": "concat-cli -f path/to/**/*.js -o bundle.js",` .. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is it gone? Will it come back?

"This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by a popular package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it."

from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat

Comment: Both concat and concat-glob-cli are available again.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the power of the shell to do what you want:

```
"scripts": {
  "concat": "cat www/js/**/*.js > all.js"},
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? It's almost like people *want* overengineering.

Comment: This creates a dependency on the shell and will not work on the standard command prompt in Windows, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, concat is gone. I was looking at this as well while moving away from gulp to pure node and found the package to be missing.

As an alternative I am now using [buildify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buildify).
Might be a slight overkill, but it works.

```
var buildify = require('buildify');
var files = [
    "./node_modules/moduleA/file1.js",
    "./node_modules/moduleB/file2.js",
];

buildify()
    .concat(files)
    .save("./dist/www/scripts/init.min.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using [concat-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-files)

And I noticed there's also [concatenate-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concatenate-files)

Both are pretty simple.

Also note writing your own is pretty simple too:

```
var output = files.map((f)=>{
  return fs.readFileSync(f).toString();
}).join(';')

fs.writeFileSync('dist/bundle.js', output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `concat` package is no longer available. I would suggest using `concat-with-sourcemaps`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-with-sourcemaps

```
var concat = new Concat(true, 'all.js', '\n');
concat.add(null, "// (c) John Doe");
concat.add('file1.js', file1Content);
concat.add('file2.js', file2Content, file2SourceMap);

var concatenatedContent = concat.content;
var sourceMapForContent = concat.sourceMap;
```