# gulp not creating `concat` file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I am trying to create `all.js` file from all `.js` files in one folder with the help of gulp. But i am not getting `all.js` file.

Steps i have followed as follows:

1. Created Gulp.js file as below

*File: gulpfile.js*

```
// grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat-util');

// create a default task and just log a message
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gutil.log('Gulp is running!')
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(['./js/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat.scripts('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

2. run `gulp` command.

After running gulp, i am getting message as `Gulp is running` as mentioned in  file. But Js file is not created.

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: See my solution for a similar question > https://stackoverflow.com/a/75336590/7472479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running the task. You need to run the command `gulp scripts`

Gulp is a task runner. It allows you to specify `tasks`. The `default` task is run when you run the `gulp` command. If you want to run a task other than the `default` task you must

1. Run `gulp {{taskname}}` where `{{taskname}}` is callback called via `gulp.task` in your `gulpfile` or
2. Call the specified task via the `default` task.

You haven't done either. So when you run `gulp` from the command line, all you are running is the `default` task, which does nothing except call `gutil.log` and then return.

Comment: with `gulp scripts` i get the error `[21:53:21] TypeError: concat.scripts is not a function`

Comment: `concat.scripts` was added in v0.5.5 (https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-concat-util/commit/759d721bd581b05bab27af9dc4087a730d5d052a). Assuming you have installed the latest version with `npm install gulp-concat-util`, it should work fine. Not sure why it doesn't work, but it should still work even without the `.scripts`. Change it to `concat('all.js')` and see if that works. You can always `console.log(concat)` inside your `scripts` task to see what's available.

Comment: sorry,.. i am new to gulp but this time it is `[22:12:30] ReferenceError: uglify is not defined`

Comment: You haven't required `uglify` at the top of your `gulpfile` where you have required everything else. Before you `var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');`, make sure you have installed it via `npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev` (Sorry, an earlier version of this comment said just to install `uglifyjs`, you need `gulp-uglify`)

Comment: New Error: `Error: Cannot find module 'uglify'` .. I hav installed via npm as well

Comment: @Gags Check my edited comment. You're supposed to install `gulp-uglify` not `uglifyjs`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135455/discussion-between-gags-and-adam).